# VBA code to copy the heading and above subtotal groups

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a macro for copying the header and insert above  all the subtotal groups. So all the subtotal groups will have a heading. I tried the below macro but it is not working.

```
Sub header()

Rows("1:1").Select

Selection.Copy

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

Col = "P"
StartRow = 1
BlankRows = 1

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(R, Col) = "Total" Then
            .Cells(R+1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your post to explain how it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. There are several tweaks:

1) I fixed the indenting. A matter of taste perhaps, but I find code hard to read if not logically indented.

2) I replaced the first two lines by Rows(1).Copy. There is no reason to select something in order to copy it (and 1 as an index is more idiomatic than "1:1")

3) The act of inserting the row completes the copy-paste operation. I thus recopied the header row after the insert operation. This fixes your actual problem

4) The final copy in the loop leaves Excel still looking for somewhere to paste the header row. Application.CutCopyMode = False addresses that.

```
Sub header()

    Rows(1).Copy
    Dim s As Range

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "P"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) = "Total" Then
                .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Rows(1).Copy
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John 

Thanks for the reply. I am a new kid in coding and I am trying to pick up the habits like 'proper intending'. Thanks for hilighting that.  

Above code didnt work first

I figured out the problem , my worksheet subtotal cell contains not only the word "Total" . How i can change the condition as "If the cell contains word Total insert the heading"

I tried to replace the line "     If .Cells(R, Col) = "Total" Then    "   with

 If InStr(1, (Range("P2:P & Count11").Value), "Total") > 1 Then

But it is giving a 400 error.

Comment: Thnks for the help , i figured out that issue.. now working perfect , Thnks again